# How to open ido completion buffer immediately on ido-insert-file

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have a directory `~/emacs/templates/matlab` with template files. When pressing a keyboard shortcut I would like to insert a given template at point in the current buffer. This can be achieved using `ido-insert-file` (see  [Buffer menu to select a set of filenames in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430290/buffer-menu-to-select-a-set-of-filenames-in-emacs) ) :

```
(defun test-ido-insert-file ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let ((default-directory "~/emacs/templates/matlab" ))
      (ido-insert-file))))
```

However, I have to press the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key twice before the `ido` completion buffer is displayed.
First, running my `test-ido-insert-file` I get the following:

[image]

then pressing the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key twice, I finally get:

[image]

How can I bring up the completion buffer immediately, avoiding pressing the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key twice?

Comment: which ubuntu(VERSION) are you using?

Comment: I am using Emacs 24.3 on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Hi @HåkonHægland, are you sure you are using `ido` because this is not ido's default behavior, have enabled `ido` by doing `(ido-mode 1)` somewhere in your init file?

Comment: @IqbalAnsari Thanks! I did not have `(ido-mode 1)`. Now it works better. But I still have to press <tab> once before I get to the completion buffer..

Comment: Actually ido is intended to be used without the completion buffer, the candidates get filtered as you type.